# Hiding the dynamic <div> tags created in SharePoint library data fetching

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am currently fetching documents from my SharePoint library and with the help of while loops, I am storing them in the pair of 5 documents per `<div>` tag. Let's suppose if there are 17 documents coming from library then there will be 4 div tags.

Now I want to display only first pair of the documents (first 5 documents in first `<div>` tag) and hide rest of the documents. I want to make an arrow button so that if user clicks on the arrow button he will be able to view the 'First Five documents + Next five documents', if he clicks again on arrow button then he will see 'first 10 documents + next five documents like that'. I tried but couldn't achieve this functionality.

```html
<head>
 <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <script>var tkAppContext = "/amgen-ndrd"</script>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
</head>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    retriveIDDSCapability();
});
</script>


<script>
var SMEFirstName= [];
var capfromlib = [];
var docname= [];
var level0 = [];
var docurl = [];
var descriptionofDocs = [];
var dept = [];

function retriveIDDSCapability()  
{    
    $.ajax  
    ({  
        url: "https://XYZ.sharepoint.com/sites/dds/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Mypersonallibrary')/items?$select=FieldValuesAsText/FileRef,Level,Function/Title,Description0,Capability/Id&$expand=FieldValuesAsText,Function,Capability",
        type: 'GET',  
        data: JSON,  
        headers:  
        {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
            "IF-MATCH": "*",  
            "X-HTTP-Method": null  
        },  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(data)   
        {  
            for (var j = 0; j < data.d.results.length; j++)   
            {  
                var item = data.d.results[j];   
                docurl[j] =  item.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef;
          docname[j] = docurl[j].replace("/sites/dds/CapBuildingDocs/", "");
                level0[j] = item.Level;
    dept[j] = item.Function.Title;
    descriptionofDocs[j] = item.Description0;
    capfromlib[j] = item.Capability.Id;
    console.log(capfromlib[j]);
          }
    getLessFaq(); 
  },
   
        error: function(data)  
        {  
            //$("#ResultDiv").empty().text(data.responseJSON.error);  
        }  
    });  
}    

function getLessFaq(){


var listItemInfo="";
listItemInfo += '<p>Showing __ of '+docurl.length+'</p>';
var i=0;
var j=0;
var k =1;
while(i<docurl.length)
 {
  j=0;
  listItemInfo += '<div id="CapDocsDiv'+k+'">';
  k++;
  while(j<5 && i<docurl.length){
  listItemInfo +=  '<p><a href="' + docurl[i] + '?web=1" target="_blank">' + docname[i]+ '</a></p><br />';
  i++;
  j++;
  }
  listItemInfo += '</div>';
 }
 $("#divListItems").html(listItemInfo);
 
 
}
 

</script>

<body>
<div id = "divListItems"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: For Handling dynamic tag use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: on is for using multiple jquerys on an element but my first issue is how to hide the rest of the div tags except the first one.